# Unable to load the UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, nib

I've been following the instructions to Alien Invaders in the "Learning Objective-C By Developing iPhone Games" Book.

I inputted the following code in the `.m` file, then the book told me to run the following code:

```
@interface GameViewController ()
    @property (strong) UIImage *playerImage;
    @property (strong) UIImageView *playerView;
@end


@implementation GameViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        //Assign an image to a variable
        self.playerImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ship.png"];

        //Create an image view and start it up with out image
        self.playerView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: self.playerImage];

         //Set the image views bounding rectangle to scale the image.
         self.playerView.frame = CGRectMake(50,400, 32,32);

         //Show the image on the screen.
         [self.view addSubview: self.playerView];
     }
}
```

I've tried to run the code in the simulator, however the following error occurs. Why is this happening?

```
Alien-Invaders[565:10012] Could not load the "backdrop.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "Chris.Alien-Invaders"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like if you look into the interface files - there is an element that references "backdrop.png". You either need to add the image or remove the element referencing it.

Comment: I haven't referenced "backdrop.png" anywhere. 

I created a GameViewController class. The only coding I have written is in the .m file (pasted in my question), which is where the book told me to code. 

I'm only a few pages in, but the book said that I should now see the background when I run my code. 

I'm fairly new to Objective-C but I feel like this book misses some key points.

Comment: @C-Smith is this a new project you started or is this an already existing project that you are adding your GameViewController into. Sounds like an existing project, there is probably stuff that you didn't create but it is referencing something that is not there.

Comment: if you don't want to go through everything, just create a new image and call it "backdrop.png" and add it to the project.

Comment: I started this project from scratch, then I added in the GameViewController class. 

I'm literally about 3 pages into creating Alien Invaders.

In the storyboard I added an image view from the object library and I set that image to "backdrop.png". 

I then coded in the GameViewController.m file (as shown in my pasted code). I was a tad concerned when the book didn't ask me to reference the "backdrop.png"... Maybe that's why the error is occurring? 

As I say, i'm all very new to this. Thanks for your help, it's much appreciated. :)

Comment: Yes you are correct in your concern - that is the issue. You have essentially told the imageview that it is going to be showing the "backdrop.png" image but there is no such image. Just leave the "Image" setting of the imageview empty/don't add the imageview until you have that "backdrop.png" image added to your project - good luck in your adventures with iOS :)

Comment: Thank-you Mike, much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the screenshot , when you drag backdrop.png to Xcode project you will see these screens , please click on Copy items If needed finish button to copy the image to your Xcode project
[image]

Comment: So what action do I need to take to make the UIImageView ("backdrop.png") appear? As I mentioned, then only coding I have written is within the GameViewController.m class. On the storyboard I dragged a UIImageView onto the screen, I then selected the "backdrop.png" image.

Comment: You can check on Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources and check that your image is present or not .

Comment: I clicked on it, but a messaged appeared saying "you need to earn a total of 15 reputation for it to show". :)